# How to show the text with inner donut chart (d3.js)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, pie-chart, donut-chart

I use the interactive function in the donut chart and also use the button function to layout the donut chart in the different years. However, I try to so many ways to let the text which is the countries (key) and also the price (value) shows in the inner donut chart, but unfortunately it cannot work!

Also, I try to type some word directly such as .text('p') in the script but it also cannot show the 'p' in the inner donut chart. So, can someone assistant this problem. Thank!

```
//This is the html

<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dount Chart</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .pie {
    margin: 20px;
    }

    .pie text {
    font-family: "Verdana";
    fill: #888;
    }

    .pie .name-text{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    }

    .pie .year-text{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .pie .price-text{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <button onclick="update(data2015)">Year 2015</button>
    <button onclick="update(data2016)">Year 2016</button>
    <button onclick="update(data2017)">Year 2017</button>
    <button onclick="update(data2018)">Year 2018</button>
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <svg width="960" height="700"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dountchart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
//This is the script
//This is the partial data which is the same data type but different years in 2017 and 2017
var data2015 = {'Country A': 380, 'Country B': 280, 'Country C': 350, 
'Country E': 425, 'Country F': 495}

var data2016 = {'Country A': 390, 'Country B': 285, 'Country C': 370, 
'Country D': 570, 'Country E': 765, 'Country F': 625}


function update(data) {

// Compute the position of each group on the pie:
var pie = d3.pie()
.value(function(d) {return d.value; })
.sort(null); // This make sure that group order remains the same in the 
 pie chart

 var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))

//for (var key in data_ready) {
    //console.log(key);     
    //console.log(data2015[key]);
//}

// map to data
 var u = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data_ready)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .append("u")
        .attr("class", "text-group");

          u.append("text")
            .attr("class", "name-text")
            .text(function(d) {return d.key; })
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('dy', '-1.2em');

          u.append("text")
            .attr("class", "price-text")
            .text(' AUD $' + `${d.value}` + ' Per Week')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('dy', '2.0em');
        })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .style("fill", color(this._current))
        .select(".text-group").remove();
      })
.attr('d', arc)
.attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i))
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this) 
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('d', arcOver)
    .style("opacity", 0.5);
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .style("cursor", "none")
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("opacity", 1.5)
    .style("fill", color(this._current));
})
.each(function(d, i) { this._current = i; });

u.append('text')
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.attr('dy', '.35em')
.text(text);

  // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
u.enter()
.append("path")
.merge(u)
.transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr('d', arc)
.attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i))


 // remove the group that is not present anymore
u
  .exit()
  .remove()

}

 // Initialize the plot with the first dataset
 update(data2015)
</script>
```

It doesn't have any error message on it but also it cannot show any text which is d.key(country) and d.value (price) in the inner donut chart.

Comment: please share `dountchart.js` code as well.

Comment: @ozil Hi, I have already shown on it which is using <script> to separate <html> and <script>, thanks!